# How to Create a simple Cursor tracking ball with JS?

Tags: javascript, html, css

I have created a simple gradient ball.

what I want to do is if I move the mouse cursor anywhere on the page created ball flows along with the mouse cursor.
I have added onmousemove event to the JS but it does't really work properly.

please show me the error in my code.

thank you!

```js
let cursor=document.querySelector('.ball');

cursor.addEventListener('onmousemove', (e)=>{
    let x= e.pageX;
    let y= e.pageY;

    cursor.style.left= x+'px';
    cursor.style.top= y+'px';
});
```

```css
.ball{
    background-image: linear-gradient(90deg, rgba(2,0,36,1) 0%, rgba(9,9,121,1) 0%, rgba(4,116,191,1) 60%, rgba(0,212,255,1) 97%);
    height: 70px;
    width: 70px;
    border-radius: 50%;
    box-shadow: 0px 0px 13px 1px rgba(9,9,121,0.73);
    transition: 0.1s;
    pointer-events: none;
    position: fixed;
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="stylesheet.css">
    <title>Document</title>
</head>
<body>
    <div class="ball"></div>

    <script src="script.js"></script>
</body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You don't need an eventListener for this. you can just use `document.onmousemove`.

Then the next issue is that you added the eventlistener to the ball not the window.

Last issue was, that you you sued `pageX` and `pageY` while the mouse position is called with `clientX` and `clientY`

```js
let cursor=document.querySelector('.ball');

document.onmousemove = function(e) {  
    let x= e.clientX;
    let y= e.clientY;

    cursor.style.left= x+'px';
    cursor.style.top= y+'px';
};
```

```css
.ball{
    background-image: linear-gradient(90deg, rgba(2,0,36,1) 0%, rgba(9,9,121,1) 0%, rgba(4,116,191,1) 60%, rgba(0,212,255,1) 97%);
    height: 70px;
    width: 70px;
    border-radius: 50%;
    box-shadow: 0px 0px 13px 1px rgba(9,9,121,0.73);
    transition: 0.1s;
    pointer-events: none;
    position: fixed;
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="stylesheet.css">
    <title>Document</title>
</head>
<body>
    <div class="ball"></div>

    <script src="script.js"></script>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: This is the same as event listener, but worse, because it overrides every other listener.

Answer (score 1):

1. you need to add the eventlistener **NOT** the **element** you need to move, 
   but to the **page** or parent element

    ❌ `cursor.addEventListener(...)` 
   ✅ `window.addEventListener(...)`

---

2. on `event-listener` you don't need to add the suffix **"on"**

    ❌ `onmousemove` 
   ✅ `mousemove`

---

```js
let cursor = document.querySelector('.ball');

window.addEventListener('mousemove', (e) => {
    let x = e.pageX;
    let y = e.pageY;

    cursor.style.left = x + 'px';
    cursor.style.top = y + 'px';
});
```

```css
.ball {
    background-image: linear-gradient(90deg, rgba(2, 0, 36, 1) 0%, rgba(9, 9, 121, 1) 0%, rgba(4, 116, 191, 1) 60%, rgba(0, 212, 255, 1) 97%);
    height: 70px;
    width: 70px;
    border-radius: 50%;
    box-shadow: 0px 0px 13px 1px rgba(9, 9, 121, 0.73);
    transition: 0.1s;
    pointer-events: none;
    position: fixed;
}
```

```html
<div class="ball"></div>
```

---

> another simplier solution can be using CSS `cursor` property: 
> https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/cursor
>
>  but for better results you need to use javascript (especially if you want to move html elements, because `cursor` need a image)

Answer (score 1):

Here is a CSS only idea if you want. You used the cursor property with an embedded SVG where you add your div with its CSS using a `foreignObject`

```css
html {
 cursor: url('data:image/svg+xml;utf8,<svg xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" width="80" height="80" viewBox="0 0 80 80"><foreignObject width="100%" height="100%"><div xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml" style="width:70%;height:70%;margin:15%;border-radius:50%;background:linear-gradient(90deg, rgba(2,0,36,1) 0%, rgba(9,9,121,1) 0%, rgba(4,116,191,1) 60%, rgba(0,212,255,1) 97%);box-shadow: 0px 0px 13px 1px rgba(9,9,121,0.73);" ></div></foreignObject></svg>')  40 40, auto;
}
```

Demo: https://codepen.io/t_afif/full/wvmaYex

Related: https://twitter.com/ChallengesCss/status/1536669474140602369